# Mail forgot password

Tags: password-recovery

In mail forgot password there is a link

http://xxx.xxxxxx.it/en/customer/account/resetpassword/?id=50&token=fagfdgdgfdbf5f6cf7d7faab34ba9e

but the my store is
http://xxx.xxxxxx.it/it/
not
http://xxx.xxxxxx.it/en/

where i can to change this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What I think happens is that in the email send function `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::sendPasswordResetConfirmationEmail` the store id attached to the loaded user is used and not the current store you are on.

> Open this file `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php`
>
> Find below code on same file.

```
public function sendPasswordResetConfirmationEmail()
{
 $storeId = $this->getStoreId();
 if (!$storeId) {
 $storeId = $this->_getWebsiteStoreId();
 }

$this->_sendEmailTemplate(self::XML_PATH_FORGOT_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, self::XML_PATH_FORGOT_EMAIL_IDENTITY,
 array('customer' => $this), $storeId);
return $this;
}
```

> Replace with below code.

```
public function sendPasswordResetConfirmationEmail()
{
  $storeId = $this->getStoreId();
  if (!$storeId) {
     $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    }  
    $this->_sendEmailTemplate(self::XML_PATH_FORGOT_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, ;
    array('customer' => $this), $storeId);
   return $this;
}
```

> For best practice,don't change core file..Put same file inside local directory like this:- app/code/local/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php
>
> **Other Solution**
>
> Please configure both store different forget password email template,Kindly review below URLs:-
>   https://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-edit-store-emails.html#gref
>   https://haijerome.wordpress.com/2010/11/24/magento-email-templates/
>
> Hope it's helpful for your.